# How to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)} = \frac{1}{kk!}$ for every $k\geqslant1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

Does anyone have any idea how to prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)} = \frac{1}{kk!}$$

Comment: Start by noticing that $k=0$ gives a divergent series, and that $k=1$ can be dealt with by a telescoping series technique.  Then investigate whether a telescoping series can be used for larger $k$.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**

Notice that

$$\small\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}=\frac1k\left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}\right)$$
and then telescope.

Comment: Replace $1$ on the numerator by 
$$\frac1k((n+k)-n)$$
and simplify.

Comment: Can I proove then that the sum of the parenthesis is $\frac{1}{k!}$?

Comment: Yes by telescoping! Notice that the two terms   in the parenthesis are two consecutive terms of a sequence.

Comment: I made it! Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome;-)

Comment: @pavlos, We find $$\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)+\frac12\left(\frac1{n(n+1)}-\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)}\right)+\frac13\left(\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\right)+\cdots$$ right?  Then how do you use Telescoping Series?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think that's right. $\frac{1} {k}$ is stable. Try writing the general term as Sami does and then write in the parenthesis the partial sum. Don't touch $\frac{1} {k}$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to solve this without telescoping.  Define $a_n=\displaystyle\frac{k!}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}$.  The partial fraction expansion of $a_n$ is  $\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^k\frac{(-1)^m{k\choose m}}{n+m}.$  Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{(-1)^m{k\choose m}}{n+m}x^{n+m},$ so that $f(0)=0$, $f(1) = a_n$, and $f'(x)=x^{n-1}(1-x)^k$, by the binomial formula.  Thus $a_n=f(1)=\int_0^1f'(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 x^{n-1}(1-x)^k\, dx$.  Then

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{k!}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{n-1}(1-x)^k\,dx.\\
&= \int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}(1-x)^{k}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1(1-x)^{k-1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{k}.
\end{align*} 
$$

Interchanging the summation and integration is valid because of monotone convergence.