# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+a)}=\frac{1}{aa!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+v)}=\frac{1}{vv!}$$
I am struggling to find a solution for this but no luck yet. How can I analyze it to get to second part?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+a)} = \frac{1}{a}\frac{(n+a)-n}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+a)} =\,\, ???$$

Comment: I have tried this but cant get any further.

Comment: It's a telescopic sum. Follow achille's advice, split into two fractions, write two consecutive terms and you will see.

Comment: Here is an idea (which might be a wrong idea): $\forall x \in [-1,1[, \, -\ln(1-x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n}$. Taking the antiderivative leads to : $\displaystyle \int -\ln(1-x) \, dx = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} x^{n+1}$. Therefore, $x - (x-1)\ln(1-x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}x^{n+1}$. Taking the limit as $x \to 1$ gives : $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = 1$. Taking the antiderivative again and, then, the limit as $x \to 1$ gives : $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{4}$...

Comment: @jibounet. Interesting idea ! Cheers

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013030/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nn1n2-nk-frac1k

Comment: its a dupe ,.,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+v)}&=&\frac{1}{v}\frac{(n+v)-n}{n(n+1)...(n+v)}\\
&=&\frac{1}{v}[\frac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+v-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)...(n+v)}]
\end{eqnarray}
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+v)}
=\frac{1}{v}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+v-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)...(n+v)}]$$
$$\frac{1}{v}\sum_{n=1}^{k}[\frac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+v-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)...(n+v)}]
=\frac{1}{v}[\frac{1}{v!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)...(k+v)}]$$
Let $k\rightarrow\infty$, then 
$\frac{1}{v}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+v-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)...(n+v)}]
=\frac{1}{v}\frac{1}{v!}$

Comment: why the second sum results to $\frac{1}{u!}$ ?

Comment: @Parhs: See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n^{\overline{r}}=\underbrace{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+r-1)}_{r\text{ terms}}$.

Hence
$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+v)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n(n+1)^{\overline{v}}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^\overline{v}(n+v)}\\
&=\frac1v\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(n)^\overline{v}}-\frac1{(n+1)^{\overline{v}}}\\
&=\frac1v\left[\left(\frac1{1^\overline{v}}-\cancel{\frac1{2^\overline{v}}}\right)+\left(\cancel{\frac1{2^\overline{v}}}-\bcancel{\frac1{3^\overline{v}}}\right)+\left(\bcancel{\frac1{3^\overline{v}}}-\cancel{\frac1{4^\overline{v}}}\right)+\cdots\right]\\
&=\frac1v \left[\frac1{1^\overline{v}}\right]\\
&=\frac1{vv!}\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$